# How to use Observable zip in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java

Recently I have come across some codes which use the following function but have difficultly in understanding how to use this function.

```
zip(java.lang.Iterable<? extends Observable<?>> ws, FuncN<? extends R> zipFunction)
```

For java doc, it said it means "Returns an Observable that emits the results of a specified combiner function applied to combinations of items emitted, in sequence, by an Iterable of other Observables.". I have read it several times but still couldn't get what it means.

And I also read that the zip function itself means "combine the emissions of multiple Observables together via a specified function and emit single items for each combination based on the results of this function".

I originally thought I know what zip does, but after reading this, I get confused. Isn't the zip function will return one value only, why it is "...for each combination based on the results of this function" ?

Anyone could help to illustrate in simple terms and examples what the above function and also the zip in general mean?

Comment: If you google the javadoc, the first result has an extended description, and a diagram. http://reactivex.io/documentation/ko/operators/zip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a example:

> Observable `X` represents the sequence `a`, `b`, `c`.
>
> Observable `Y` represents the sequence `α`, `β`, `γ`.
>
> Zipping the observables `X` and `Y` using the function `f` returns a
>   new observable that represents the sequence `f(a, α)`, `f(b, β)`,
>   `f(c, γ)`.

If you want an even more concrete example,

> Observable `X` represents the sequence `2`, `3`, `4`.
>
> Observable `Y` represents the sequence `5`, `6`, `7`.
>
> Zipping the observables `X` and `Y` using the "multiply" function returns a
>   new observable that represents the sequence `10`, `18`,
>   `28`.

In the JavaDoc, "a specified combiner function" refers to the function `f`. The phrase "a specified function" in the second thing that you quoted also refers to this. Notice how this function combines multiple items, one from each observable, (e.g. `2` and `5`) to one single item in the returned observable (e.g. `10`).

A "combination" in both the JavaDoc and the second thing you quoted refers to tuples of items from each observable that you are zipping, such as `(2, 5)` or `(3, 6)`.

Note that `zip` returns one single `Observable` object, which represents a *sequence* of values. The JavaDoc describes this single `Observable` object, whereas the second thing you quoted describes the *sequence represented by* the `Observable` object (hence the wording "for each combination"). This could be why you have misunderstood the second excerpt as saying that `zip` returns multiple values. Both excerpts are telling the truth, but they are describing different things.

I reiterate: `zip` returns a *single* `Observable` object that represents a *sequence* of values.